# While loop wont loop with inFile

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program that reads in a `.txt` file. The program is supposed to read a character, output an error, and continue reading the rest of the lines, and follow suit. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <stream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    double runningTotal;
    int c = 0;

    string fileName;
    ifstream infile;
    cout << "Enter a file name\n";
    cin >> fileName;

    infile.open(fileName.c_str());

    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cout<<"Error! invalid entry please retry!\n";
    }
    else {
        string line;
    
        int a, b;
        while (!inflile.fail()) {
            infile >> a >> b;
            c = a + b;
            runningTotal = c;
            cout <<a<<" + "<<b<<" = " << runningTotal<<endl;             
        }
        getline(infile, line, '\n');
        if (infile.fail()){
            getline(infile, line, '\n');
            cout<<"stop being stupid\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted won't compile, because it has a typo in the `while` loop condition. Can you please also show what the input looks like and what you are expecting the output to be?

Comment: Your description and what the program is trying to do do not match. One problem with your program is the `while` condition. Replace it with `infile >> a >> b`.

Comment: Your code does not validate that `operator>>` is successful before using the integers. And when it does eventually fail, the subsequent calls to `getline()` will also fail, because you are not `clear()`'ing the stream's error state.

Comment: O.T.: Guess what I would think/feel (about the app. developer) when an application would prompt me to "stop being stupid" (instead of providing a sufficient error message which explains what is expected and why my input wasn't)... (Nevertheless, I always believed that an (over-)kindly complaint might hurt really stupid users even more.)